# Shell file busy

Tags: node.js, shell, fs

I have written a code to open a file , write a little mongodb export script , and then executing it , but this is what i am getting ( although the file is being created and written in ) , i will share the code snippet.

note : this code is running perfectly on local host but not on our server ( ec2 .. )

```
let baseDir = "/Users/tarekhabche/Desktop/awsTest";
      const today = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss");
      console.log(baseDir);
      //fs.unlinkSync(`${baseDir}/result.sh`);
      //setting the permissions to 777
      fs.open(`${baseDir}/result.sh`, "wx", 0o777, (err, desc) => {
        if (!err && desc) {
          //writing the file
          fs.writeFile(
            desc,`mongoexport --db=graphqlAmazonV4 --collection=purchasefromappobjectmodels   --type=csv  --fields=purchaseDate,idfa,status  --query '{"purchaseDate": { "$gte" : { "$date" : "${startDate}"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "${endDate}"}}}' --out=results/result."${today}".csv`,
            (err) => {
              // Rest of your code
              if (err) throw err;
            }
          );
        }

        //executing the shelll script
        setTimeout(function exeecPurchaseReport() {
          var yourscript = exec("./result.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
          });
        }, 3000);
      });
```

I tried fs.unlink before opening the file and writing the script but it didn't work

Comment: You are sure the path for baseDir is corret on your Server ?

Comment: yes it is var/www/html , i use nginx

Comment: I am not an aws expert bt I would assume baseDir = "/Users/tarekhabche/Desktop/awsTest" is wrong or not the code which runs on the server

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running the script directly , without rewriting the file over and over then executing.

```
setTimeout(function exeecPurchaseReport() {
        var yourscript = exec(
          `mongoexport --db=graphqlAmazonV4 --collection=purchasefromappobjectmodels   --type=csv  --fields=purchaseDate,idfa,status  --query '{"purchaseDate": { "$gte" : { "$date" : "${startDate}"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "${endDate}"}}}' --out=results/result."${today}".csv`,
          (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            console.log(stdout);
            console.log(stderr);
          }
        );
      }, 3000);
```